# Rolling over time series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I am working on a stock data. I have a set of time series as shown in the table. I would like to calculate the columns score_pos, score_Neg and score_Nut. The idea behind these columns is to find out the (positive change)* (score in last 15minutes) for score_pos, (negative change)* (score in last 15min) for score_neg and (neutral change)* (score in last 15minutes) for score_Nut.

For example: If we take the time (12.15 to 12.30), I need to check the time 12.30 and see if that direction was Pos or Neg or Nut. This means that if the direction was going in positive direction or Negative or Neutral. In the row 16 we can see that the score_Pos is 5 because the direction is positive at this point and i am counting the total count of positive until this time. This is the goal. Next i do for every row. For this row i will check previous 15minutes from this row which would be (3:17).

I tried the following code to compute these columns.

```
co=df.Direction[df.Direction=='Pos'].dropna()
for c in co:
    df[c] = df['Direction'].eq(c).rolling('15min').sum()
df.loc[:df.index[0] + pd.Timedelta(15*60, unit="s"), cols] = np.nan
```

This code doesn't work as expected. I am not sure how to compute this in a better way.

```
row      Timestamp     Direction  score   score_pos   score_Neg  score_Nut

 1    1/20/19 12:15    
 2    1/20/19 12:17    Pos        564.8
 3    1/20/19 12:17    Nut         
 4    1/20/19 12:18    Neg        -4.7
 5    1/20/19 12:19    Neg        -17.3
 6    1/20/19 12:20    Pos         4.9
 7    1/20/19 12:21    Neg        -0.02
 8    1/20/19 12:22    Neg        -3.50
 9    1/20/19 12:23    Pos         62.43
 10   1/20/19 12:24    Neg        -4.6
 11   1/20/19 12:25    Pos         2.8
 12   1/20/19 12:26    Neg         3.4
 13   1/20/19 12:27    Neg        -0.7
 14   1/20/19 12:29    Neg         8.07
 15   1/20/19 12:29    Neg        -0.73                 -19.8
 16   1/20/19 12:30    Nut         0                              0
 17   1/20/19 12:31    Pos        -2.6          67.52         
 18   1/20/19 12:32    Neg        -0.2                  -20.0
 19   1/20/19 12:33    Pos         5.2          72.76
```

Comment: You're code looks fine, only 2 comments: I think the first line should be c=df['Direction'].unique(). And you're still missing the (equal to Direction condition) which should be easy to add at the end. It would be easier to help if you add some sample data that we can run to test it.

Comment: @ecortazar Please check now, I have updated with some more sample data and which is what i exactly need. The expected values on columns are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is either a problem with the explanation of your issue or with the example you pasted, because they are not coherent.

Here is my proposal for what you described in the text.

EDITED: This now handles NaNs in the Direction column (it ignores them). And duplicated values in the timestamp column.

```
df = df.set_index('Timestamp')

for state in df['Direction'].dropna().unique():
    df.loc[df['Direction'] == state, 'score_' + state] = df.loc[df['Direction'] == state,'score'].fillna(0).rolling('15T').sum()

new_columns = 'score_' + df['Direction'].dropna().unique()
df.loc[:df.index[0] + pd.DateOffset(minutes=14), new_columns] = np.nan
```

Comment: Btw i get this error  TypeError: must be str, not float

Comment: =IF(O16="Pos",SUMIF($O2:$O16,"Pos",$Q2:$Q16),"") -> I use this formula in excel to calculate those columns. I hope your solution does the same. Also, i dont understand why its not coherent. If i see the values in columns its calculated as per the logic i used.

Comment: the solution you gave is giving the error as mentioned above. I tried to add dropna() next to unique() and it some what gave same answer but it could give only the pos_score column and for next columns it gave error like `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

Comment: @KSp The motive for those errors are as follows: (1) There are NaNs in the Direction column (I'd make sure that data is clean before you run this). (2) There are duplicated dates in the Timestamp column. This last one can be observed in the example data as well (For example, 1/20/19 12:29 is duplicated). This will produce error since the rolling operator is ill-defined for this situation. Please clarify if this is expected behavior in you data.

Comment: indeed you are totally right, the direction column has nan values but the timestamp has no nan values. But may be duplicated for sure. So i cant make any calculations?without dropping nan? if you see in this link i worked on same data with nan but that code works fine?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276372/looking-at-previous-time-series

Comment: I've edited the answer regarding your comment. Though I'd be careful with the handling of NaNs.

Comment: The only value i get wrong is instead 67.52 i get 632.4156235 which is because the row is not comparing from o4:o18. but it counts the total of 15minutes